# Openoffice Calc does not extend formula on cells

Tags: spreadsheet, openoffice

I am on this CentOS machine, fighting with openoffice 3 `Calc`, just to do some very simple operations.
I have a column of values, and I want to perform the same operation on a certain number of consecutive cells of that column.
I tried to write the formula in the cell, and then extend the box, but this does not give the expected result: instead of "extending" the formula, another dialog window is open asking in which way I want to `fill`. Whatever thing I chose it gives results that are different from the formula applied to that cell.

Also, copying and pasting does not work.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What is your formula? Did you hit enter, before copying the formula value to multiple adjacent cells? Any relative cell references will of course change if you don't "escape" them with `$`.

Comment: My formula is just a subtraction or a division. Let's say `B3 - 0.1`. Yes, I did hit enter. What do you mean by `escaping with $`?

Comment: That should be `=B3-0.1` if you copy that down one cell, it will become `=B4-0.1` unless you make it `=B$3-0.1` to escape the row number and fix the row number to `3`

Comment: No, I do not escape. If I edit in that way, I receive `Err:522`.

Comment: Error 522 might mean you should enable iterations: Menu `Tools` -> `Options` Then select `OpenOffice.org Calc` -> `Calculate` and set `Iterations`

Comment: Ok, sounds right, I had looked for this error, but did not find any reference to the necessity of enabling iterations. Last thing: is it possible to act on one cell itself, or should I use a different column to make the formula effective? That is, `B3` has a value of `1.1`. I want to do, `B3-0.1` (and then the same on the down cells). Can I use this formula directly on `B3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 522 probably means you should enable iterations: `Menu Tools` -> `Options` Then select `OpenOffice.org Calc` -> `Calculate` and set `Iterations`.

You cannot put a direct reference to a cell itself in the cell. You will need to make a new column (or the same cell on a different sheet) to give it a start value. IIRC The problem is that there is no initial value (like you might expect 0 to be) for self directly self referencing formulas, hence the iteration doens't know how to start.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more question: how do I copy that column in whatever place of that or another sheet? If I just copy and paste, the pasted column refers to the operation stored, not to the values in the column itself. Thus, I receive error.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but I think what you want is to go to the top cell where you want the copy, type `=` then select the top cell with the formula and drag that value over the whole column